# Error: "you need at least 8.6GB disk space to install SecurityOnion, This computer has only 2 GB"

Tags: virtual-machines, qemu, gns3

[required disk size is more than 8GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu3bH.png)

[But got only 2GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nko7N.png)

In `GNS3` I imported securityonion-16.04.6.1.iso image as `new qemu vm`, not as `existing qemu vm`. These is no where an option to change/choose enough disk size, the only option I got is to select RAM size and number of CPU-cores. But the disk size assigned to the VM is just 2 GB, which is not sufficient to install the complete image.

Alternatively, I installed `qemu` on my host machine, and there I can choose the disk size, ram and number of cores. So the os image installed perfectly. Now I tried importing the VM as `existing qemu vm` on `GNS3`. But I could not see it listed.

How can I increase the disk size so that I can complete the installation of `securityonion` OS on `GNS3`

Operating System: linux ubuntu 18.04
GNS3 Software Version: GNS3 2.1.18

Answer (score 1):

**Please take a backup of your virtual hard disk file before attempting to resize it.**

Before resizing a virtual machine's disk file, ensure that it is turned off. Locate the file and then use `qemu-img` to add more space to the disk file. Like this to add 15 gigabytes:

`sudo qemu-img resize securityonion.qcow2 +15G`

However, it appears from your screenshot that you are using the LiveCD ISO as your hard drive based on the ISO9660 filesystem. When creating a virtual machine, make sure to create a **new** virtual hard disk file and using the optical drive for your installer ISO.